# Can't close div after remote content loaded - Jquery

Tags: jquery

The last 5 lines I'm wanting to collapse the div that becomes populated with content on the first click from an external file.

I've tried numerous events with no luck:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {
        $("li.span3 a").click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();   
            jQuery('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: jQuery('.content').offset().top -100 }, 'fast');
            $('.content').load(this.href).delay(2000);
        });
        $("li.span3 a").click(function(){
            $('.content').unload();
            $('.content').addclass().css('height', '0px');
        });
    });
```

The content sits as an empty div on the target page, for the content to be loaded in.to

Comment: can you create a http://jsfiddle.net to show your problem

Comment: are you wanting to click the same element again to unload the content?

Comment: Yeah basically to close or hide the div to original, non-visible state. Theres basically thumbnail images and once one of them is clicked, a section above them will expand with more detail on the corresponding image clicked.

Comment: Just doing a fiddle now, thanks.

Comment: I was going to suggest that you either unbind the click event and rebind it to the new one once the element is clicked or do some sort of check within the click function, like simon's answer, which would be the easier way to go

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this works for you?

```
var $content = $('.content');

$(".span3").on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    if($content.hasClass('loaded') {
        $content.hide().removeClass('loaded');
    } else {
        $('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $content.offset().top -100 }, 'fast');
        $content.load(this.href).show().addClass('loaded');
    }
});
```

Comment: Lifesaver, thanks! I now just need to figure why the scroll to increments further down the page each time i click.